# MKMapView get distance between coordinates on customized route

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationdistance

I have a custom route on map and want to get the distance between two coordinates on `MKMapView`. Below are the steps I have done so far...

1. I have grabbed coordinate points and prepared an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` (like, `customRoute = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]`).
2. To show the route, using array of coordinates, I have drawn `MKPolyline` using `MKOverlay` method.
3. And calculating the distance between two coordinates using `distanceFromLocation` method.

When I calculate distance, the resulting distance is a straight line distance but not based on directions.

Lets say a user is at location A (on custom route) and wants to reach location B (on custom route). So all I want to calculate is the distance between A and B (not straight line distance).

Right now I'm finding out the nearest coordinate from the user location and calculating the distance to the destination by looping through the array of coordinates. But this doesn't give the proper result when there are multiple routes and the nearest point is on the other route.

One thing struck my mind was to set the custom directions on map and find the distance, but I've no idea on how to achieve this.

Language being used is Swift.

Any kind of help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs on `distanceInMeters`:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:)

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.

So the method in fact returns a "straight line."

As far as I know, you'll need to create individual `MKRoute` objects between each section of your custom route, calculate those individual distances, then combine them.

As I've explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23572608/2274694) answer, you can calculate each individual MKRoute's distance by fetching the `MKDirectionsResponse` like so:

```
let request:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

// source and destination are the relevant MKMapItems
request.setSource(source)
request.setDestination(destination)

// Specify the transportation type
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile;

// If you're open to getting more than one route, 
// requestsAlternateRoutes = true; else requestsAlternateRoutes = false;
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
    (response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in

    if error == nil {
        self.directionsResponse = response
    }
})
```

then getting the distance like so:

```
let route = directionsResponse.routes[currentRoute] as MKRoute
let distance = route.distance
```

Comment: I somehow feel this's the only way to get it done. The thing is there're no directions on ios maps for the route I have set, so does this consider the custom route I have set and calculate the distance based on the coordinates I have provided?

Comment: @SrujanSimha Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough, but I think you'll have to do it piece by piece... Like calculate from point A to point B, then point B to point C, etc then add up all the distances.